# How to Cache fonts (.woff, woff2, .ttf, .eot) in Wildfly 10?

Tags: caching, fonts, wildfly

I have font files within my JSF 2.2 project with Primefaces 5.3 and Omnifaces 2.3 and need to put these text font files (as .woff and .woff2) within the wildfly cache but unfortunately I'm not getting.

Image files (.gif, .png) and CSS files are in the cache, only text fonts that are not in the cache.

I used the tips from this site, but still could not make it work: https://gist.github.com/remibantos/5e86829e1ba6ad64eea1

I put these predicate within the wildlfy: `... path-suffix [ '.woff2'] or path-suffix [ '.woff2.xhtml'],` and yet I can not have the cache.

Follows the code WildFly 10 to use to perform the cache:

> standalone-full.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
        <server name="default-server">
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <filter-ref name="custom-max-age" predicate="path-suffix['.js'] or path-suffix ['.js.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.json'] or path-suffix ['.json.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.html'] or path-suffix ['.css'] or path-suffix ['.css.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.jpg'] or path-suffix ['.jpg.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.jpeg'] or path-suffix ['.jpeg.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.png'] or path-suffix ['.png.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.gif'] or path-suffix ['.gif.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.eot'] or path-suffix ['.eot.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.ttf'] or path-suffix ['.ttf.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.woff'] or path-suffix ['.woff.xhtml'] or path-suffix ['.woff2'] or path-suffix ['.woff2.xhtml']"/>
            </host>
        </server>

        <filters>
            <response-header name="custom-max-age" header-name="Cache-Control" header-value="max-age=64800000, public"/>
        </filters>

    </subsystem>
```

Please, help me with this problem.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I found that the problem was that I was not using ssl. if I enable ssl (https) the cache usually happens.

Then during the development of the site I'm using http, when I need to experiment with cache I use https.

I do not know why this happens but at least figured out how to solve this problem and continue development.

Thank you truly for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add disable-caching-for-secured-pages="false" I think it will also work with non-https

```
<servlet-container name="default" disable-caching-for-secured-pages="false">
```

Comment: Hi rasmusvhansen, I add  disable-caching-for-secured-pages="false" in servlet-container and the server don't do the cache in http, only in https.
thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: if you have any other way to solve this please let me know.